# shape-outside in the middle of a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Like in the reference photo I want to display some paragraphs in to columns and I want that a middle paragraph sits in the middle of the parent div. The text of the paragraphs should wrap around the middle paragraph + some margin.

[Reference Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMIxt.png)

Here is the code for the text

```
<div class="sC-content-wrapper">
  <?php
  $text = $data->firstParagraph();
  $paragraphs = explode("\n\n", $text);
  $middleParagraph = $data->secondParagraph();


  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    ?>
    <p class="normal-paragraph">
      <?= $paragraph ?>
    </p>
  <?php } ?>

  <div class="middle-paragraph-container">
    <p class="middle-paragraph">
      <?= $middleParagraph ?>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using shape-outside but that apparently only works when the float is set to right or left.
Is there an alternative way or workound?

Answer (score 2):

If it is plausible, split the paragraphs into the columns and have them as separate column elements. Use a floated element at the start of both columns to provide the box that the text wraps around. In one of the floated columns, have the text inside.

```html
<div style="display: flex; gap: 1rem">
  <div style="flex-basis: 1 1 0%;">
    <div style="margin-top: 10rem; height: 8rem; width: 9rem; float: right; outline: 1px solid #f499; shape-outside: inset(50% 0 0 0); margin-right: -6rem; padding: 1rem">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula lobortis ornare. Integer purus lectus, feugiat a vulputate et, consequat non dui. Vivamus elit ante, ultricies ac massa ut, imperdiet lobortis magna. In sit amet ligula porta, varius
      massa lacinia, lobortis nunc. Integer quam elit, lobortis ut eros quis, ultrices tristique urna. In et scelerisque ligula, vitae ultricies lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam
      et lobortis velit. Curabitur suscipit vel nulla a posuere. Suspendisse eu enim eget dolor porta mollis. Praesent at accumsan dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Fusce tincidunt est sit amet dapibus venenatis. Proin quis leo feugiat, ultrices tellus a, sodales ante. Quisque vel leo sem. Suspendisse massa nisi, euismod viverra risus at, ultricies laoreet nisl. Nullam eros turpis, dignissim vel ex a, dapibus eleifend
      nunc. Integer tristique elementum ante, nec bibendum mi pulvinar consectetur. Nulla vel lacinia lectus. Proin vulputate augue non purus malesuada, lobortis venenatis lectus facilisis. Aenean luctus lectus eu orci consequat, vitae congue risus vestibulum.
      Aenean ligula turpis, pharetra ut lorem a, molestie euismod eros. Aenean id gravida nulla, ac semper purus. Nullam dui nibh, pulvinar in viverra ut, dapibus quis sapien.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-basis: 1 1 0%;">
    <div style="height: 20rem; width: 5rem; float: left; outline: 1px solid #0489; shape-outside: inset(50% 0 0 0)"></div>
    <p>
      Vestibulum a nibh dolor. Sed fringilla elementum faucibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec tempor consectetur bibendum. Praesent lorem nisl, pharetra finibus iaculis vitae, lobortis in tellus.
      Pellentesque eu lacinia velit. Sed et justo ornare, ornare massa non, vulputate diam. Suspendisse tempus velit sed porta consectetur. Vestibulum tincidunt nisl vitae sapien sagittis, in venenatis quam congue.
    </p>
    <p>
      Duis urna nulla, hendrerit non neque sed, tincidunt auctor nunc. Vestibulum pharetra posuere eleifend. Nulla vel nibh nisl. Fusce felis diam, laoreet eget convallis quis, hendrerit congue quam. Aliquam faucibus urna pharetra arcu sodales iaculis et a
      risus. Curabitur faucibus elit metus, non euismod eros congue in. Praesent egestas sapien dolor, ac molestie elit finibus commodo. Donec neque magna, scelerisque lacinia arcu at, porta pharetra magna. Duis sit amet tortor dolor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla tempor iaculis lacus, at blandit dui dignissim eget. Proin non urna tempus nisl dapibus aliquam. Vivamus vitae nulla rutrum, consectetur libero vel, tempor eros. Nulla laoreet consequat lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris laoreet
      ligula sit amet sagittis semper. Etiam dictum enim sed dolor auctor dictum. Aenean sagittis interdum neque, a molestie nisl accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse quis risus tincidunt, rhoncus felis quis, porta orci. Nulla facilisis viverra neque. Morbi
      risus lorem, ultrices blandit felis a, volutpat dapibus nunc. Nullam at porttitor lacus. Donec lectus arcu, egestas in metus at, pellentesque placerat nisi. Proin sit amet vestibulum urna. Suspendisse scelerisque luctus euismod. Maecenas diam purus,
      tristique at nulla sit amet, pellentesque ullamcorper lacus.
    </p>
```

Comment: If I try this with my texts the two columns are no longer symmetric in width and no longer split in the middle of the parent div